# Capture File name from File Browser Item Field in Oracle Apex

Tags: forms, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to capture file_name and store it in another item field at run time using dynamic action.
I tried it to capture File Browser Item field but its capturing entire file path.

Please suggest if this can be done using PLSQL or JS in Oracle Apex 4.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression, relying on the fact that there is always a backslash before the filename:

```
$('#P6_FILE').val().match(/\\([^\\]*)$/)[1]
```

explaining the regular expression:

1. \\ double backslash: escaping the backlash
2. () parenthesis to dig out the filename from the result that initially includes backslashes
3. [^\\]* any letter that is not a backslash, as many times as you'd like
4. $ end of string

Stackoverflow sometimes escapes backslashes itself, so this might look messy

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but its not working, also other DAs to hide and show the items stopped working.

Comment: There's a period missing between `.val()` and `match(`. You may have to make minor adjustments to the code to fit your needs.

Comment: could you please help me with real time example

Comment: I tried with PLSQL code but it works in sql developer but its not working in Apex:

`declare
v_doc varchar2(100);
v_pos number;
v_name varchar2(100);

begin

v_name := :P59_DOCUMENT;
select instr(v_name,'\') into v_pos from dual;
v_pos := v_pos+1;
select --'test'
substr(v_name, v_pos) into v_doc from dual;
:P59_DOCNAME:= v_doc;
end;`

Comment: It seems like a bad call to send the value to the server only to perform the regular expression. I edited in the missing period @DanMcGhan pointed, try it :)
  
  if it works, please also vote up my answer

Comment: If you do decide to use PL/SQL, use the RegExp_substr function:
select
REGEXP_SUBSTR('C://path/to/file.extention','/([^/]*)$',1,1,null,1)
from dual;
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099

Comment: YotamWIS Constantini
Regexp is also not working to fetch document name from file name in plsql expression or sql query, however it works perfectly in sql dev on DB.

Comment: not working:
`declare
v_doc varchar2(100);
v_name varchar2(100);
begin
v_name := :P59_DOCUMENT;
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_name ,'/([^/]*)$',1,1,null,1) into v_doc from dual;
:P59_DOCNAME:= v_doc;
end;`

working:

`begin

:P59_DOCNAME:= :P59_DOCUMENT;
end;`
working but exact name of path, and worried why above code is not working in DA.

Answer (score 0):

$('#P6_FILE').val().match(/\([^\]*)$/)[1]

this has worked in DA set value

Answer (score 0):

I use this SQL to get the file name from the file browser :

```
select filename
FROM apex_application_temp_files
where name = :P2_FILE_SELECT;
```

P2_FILE_SELECT is the file browser item.

Write this SQL into "SQL Query" of SOURCE.